# Does calling entityManager.find() require an EntityTransaction?

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, transactions

I would like to search both the current persistence context, and if necessary, the supporting database for the existence of an entity.  This is a stand-alone java-se application. (It will not run in a java-ee application container.)  I don't need to worry about being thread-safe.  Do I need to query the database within the context of an EntityTransaction?

Is there an underlying difference one way or the other?

```
entityManager.getTransaction.begin();
MyEntity me = entityManager.find(MyEntity.class, myEntity.getPrimaryKey());
entityManager.getTransaction.commit();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No for a **read only** operations it is not required.

Placing a lock of type **FORE_VERSION_INCREMENT** or some other higher level locks are turning the operation into **not** being read only. In this case, it needs transactions.

Answer (score 1):

There are certain situations (involving locks) in which `find` does require transactional handling.

Referring to the official [JPA specification](http://download.oracle.com/otn-pub/jcp/persistence-2_1-fr-eval-spec/JavaPersistence.pdf) (final version, JPA 2.1) in Section 3.1.1 (page 79) we find:

> The `find` method (provided it is invoked *without* a lock or invoked with LockModeType.NONE)
>   and the `getReference` method are **not** required to be invoked within a transaction.

In the scenario described you are safe to call `em.find(..)`**without** an `EntityTransaction`.

Hope it helps.

Comment: My answer is 100% correct, because in the situations you mention they are not READ_ONLY. in The moment you place a lock the version field will jump and the operation will no longer be READ_ONLY therefore you will need transaction. But as long as you keep READ_ONLY operations transactions are NOT NEEDED. And if you read me again, this is what I have said in my post for "as long as it is read only, no transactions needed"